# Saving the hashed image file name from public/image folder into the column of a database table in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

How can I save an image name from **public/image** folder into the database table named user_account with a column name of photo_filename.

**This is the one being saved** How can i remove the public/image/?

[image]

**Instead of this one**

[image]

**Controller.php file**

```
public function avatarUpload(Request $request,){
    $data = UserModel::where('app_id', '=' ,Session::get('loginId'))->first();
    $path = $request->file('image')->store('public/image');

   
    
    $validator=Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'photo_filename' => 'required',
        'photo_filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:5000'
        ]);
    $data->update([
        'photo_filename' => $path
    ]);

    return $path;
}
```

Comment: So you have a string in `$path`, that contains 'public/image' and then the rest. You want to `replace` that 'public/image', with nothing (empty string). Look into the php function called `str_replace()`, it might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the answer to my silly question. Just use basename($var)

**Controller.php file**

```
public function avatarUpload(Request $request,){
$data = UserModel::where('app_id', '=' ,Session::get('loginId'))->first();
$path = $request->file('image')->store('public/image');
$filename = basename($path);



$validator=Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'photo_filename' => 'required',
    'photo_filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:5000'
    ]);
$data->update([
    'photo_filename' => $filename
]);

return $path;
```

}